# Regreso al comienzo de un SWITCH, dias de la semana

Tags: c, bucles

Saludos tengo este programa sencillo que anuncia los dias de la semana del 1 al 7, pero yo quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer que en caso de una entrada errónea (número distinto fuera del margen 1-7), me lance un mensaje de error y vuelva al scanf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
int dia;
printf("Escriba el número de día: \n");
scanf("%d",&dia);
switch(dia)
  {
  case 1: printf("El día es Lunes");
  break;
  case 2: printf("El día %d es Martes",dia);
  break;
  case 3: printf("El día %d es Miércoles",dia);
  break;
  case 4: printf("El día %d es Jueves",dia);
  break;
  case 5: printf("El día %d es Viernes",dia);
  break;
  case 6: printf("El día %d es Sábado",dia);
  break;
  case 7: printf("El día %d es Domingo",dia);
  break;
  default: printf("El día no existe");
  }
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Colócalo dentro de un loop

Answer (score -1):

Proba poniéndole un if que analice si el número ingresado está en el margen 1-7, si lo está que pase al switch y de los resultados deseados. Si es más grande que de un mensaje de error.

```
        ...
        if(día>=1 && día<=8) {
        switch...} /* el switch mandado en la pregunta*/
        else{
        printf("ingrese número del 1-7");
        }...
```

Comment: Por algo está el `default`

Comment: no funciono con esa correcion :(  alguien mas me puede ayudar